# Creating a Massive List with many smaller Lists inside

Tags: java

I've searched around and can't find exactly what I'm looking for. So here I am reading data from a file and would want to create a massive list of user objects and smaller lists inside which will hold the information of the user. My end goal is for something similar to this:
[[user info], [user info], [user info], [user info]]. So that I can use methods and call upon certain parts of the user's information such as his/her name, user id etc

The User's information is formatted as such:

[image: Image Depicting what information is set out by the user]

And here is an example of some information:

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

bin1:x:1:1:bin1:/bin1:/sbin/nologin

eg:2:2:eg:/sbin:/sbin/nologin

eg2:3:4:eg2:/var/eg2:/sbin/nologin

```
public class PasswordFile {

private String username, password, comments, homeDir, loginShell, UID, GID;

User user;
ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

public PasswordFile() {
    BufferedReader br;
    FileReader fr;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Java_Application\\Labs\\Lab 5s\\DataFile");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        br.readLine(); // this is used to read the first line of the code
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String arrOfStr[] = line.split(Pattern.quote(":"));
            for (String x : arrOfStr) {
                // insert code here
                username = arrOfStr[1];
                password = arrOfStr[2];
                UID = arrOfStr[3];
                GID = arrOfStr[4];
                comments = arrOfStr[5];
                homeDir = arrOfStr[6];
                loginShell = arrOfStr[7];

            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException error_FileNotFoundException) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong in the opening of the file! ERROR FILE NOT FOUND");
    } catch (IOException error_IoException) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong in the reading of the file! ERROR");
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt at coding and finding a solution to my issue. Any and all insight for my problem is welcome as I am unsure whether one massive list would be appropriate or just having many smaller lists of information would work better.

Comment: Very confused about the lists inside of lists part... why not keep it an `ArrayList<User>` ?

Comment: inside of your loop, create a User object and add it to your list of users.... what are you planning on doing with the results?

Comment: also get rid of the loop entirely and replace with `userList.add(new User(arrOfStr[0],arrOfStr[1],......))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you split the line I would recommend you do the following:

- Create a class called something like `UserInfo` and populate an instance of that 
  class with the password fields.
- Then you can create a `Map<String, UseInfo>` to be able to retrieve that information using the `username` as a key to the map.

```
class UserInfo {
   String username;
   int gid;
   int uid;
   // and so forth.
}
```

The Map could be

```
Map<String, UserInfo> users = new TreeMap<>();
```

Using a `TreeMap` will maintain a sorted map based on the userID key.